# Eclipse not implementing .class files that are provided, and not able to super those classes in the project

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have scoured this website for the answer, but none of the solutions I have found worked for me. Please mark as duplicate and paste link if you know that post is the answer.

Anyway, what is happening is I am using Eclipse for my Java project. My professor emailed us classes that he coded and wants us to use for part of the project. I have not been able to figure out for the life of me how eclipse imports these .class files into the project. I have tried several solutions from other posts like linking the folder with the .class files, and none of that worked.

The reason I know it does not work is because I am supposed to be able to do "extends MessageState" etc. (MessageState is one of the .class files he sent us), and yet I get an error that Eclipse doesn't know what that is referencing (because it thinks it does not exist). The classes he sent are all super classes of my subclasses that I have to code myself in the project.

Let me know any ideas you have and I will try them out.

"EDIT"

The link provided was the first thing I tried, and it does not work. I still am getting an error in my class that *extends* one of the classes he provided to us. I need to use what is in his superclasses (.class, not .java) for my subclasses (.java) that I am currently writing. Here is what it looks like:

```
public class ServerBeginState extends MessageState
```

The error is on the "MessageState" which eclipse says: "MessageState cannot be resolved to a type"

This would mean that MessageState doesn't exist and needs to be created, but for some reason I am not linking the classes to this project correctly. That is what I am asking the question for.

Comment: Did your professor give you `.java` files or a `jar` file?

Comment: You'll have to package them as a `.jar` (Oracle has tutorials on this) and then add the `.jar` as a dependency to your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding .class files to an Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328548/adding-class-files-to-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: He sent us .class files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just decompiled the .class files and made them into new .java files. That seemed to have worked, but if someone finds a way to use .class files for implementation in eclipse (because i know it works in Textpad 8) please post an answer.

Comment: You can add a folder with class files to your project like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328865/5646962

Answer (score -1):

Simply Create a new java project.
Then drag and drop the classes sent by your Professor in the folder named source code or "***src***" .
Eclipse will produce a pop up window with 2 options make sure you select "copy files"
if that does not work try manually copying the files in your src code location which will be found in your java project folder.

Comment: That doesn't work for `.class` files - they aren't source code.